# Apache, Django and mod_wsgi

Tags: server, apache2, django

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 and trying to configure my Apache server with Django. I tried a couple of different online tutorials and keep on getting errors. This is my latest error when I try to start my server:

```
 * Starting web server apache2  
     apache2: Syntax error on line 214 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:
     Syntax error on line 2 of /etc/apache2/httpd.conf: 
     Cannot load /etc/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi.so into server: 
     /etc/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi.so: 
     cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Action 'start' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
                                                                 [fail]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure `libapache2-mod-wsgi` is installed, and that it is enabled:

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi
sudo a2enmod wsgi
```

If you're using Python3 you might need `libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3` instead. They can't both be installed at the same time but they both use the same `a2enmod` command to enable in Apache.

Comment: Thanks @Dan, I'll alter the muttering at the end of the answer.